# How to close an app in the ios simulator by command line

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, instruments

I want to quit an app in the script by the end of my test.
I know the `command+shift+hh` can quit an app in Simulator, but I want to quit by command line.

[image: code]

Is there a good way to solve my problem?

Comment: provide the code in question, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

I do like below:

```
# set you bundle identifier
bundle_id=<com.myapp>
# find running device
device=$(xcrun simctl list | grep 'Booted' | awk -F'[()]+' '{print $2}')
# terminate it
xcrun simctl terminate $device $bundle_id
```

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, you can send the process SIGTERM or SIGKILL using the kill command:

```
kill <pid>
kill -9 <pid>
```

Comment: this will kill the `simulator` process and not the app itself

Answer (score 0):

I tried `xcrun simctl help` and there is a `terminate` action: `xcrun simctl <SIMULATOR_ID> <BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER>`.
when you use it, the app will still appear as if it is in the background but it's like you click the 'stop' button in xcode.

if you wish to do that as part of an automation process, you can also terminate the simulator, if that covers your needs with `xcrun simctl shutdown <SIMULATOR_ID>`.

you can also reopen the simulator with the command `xcrun simctl boot <SIMULATOR_ID>`

when the simulator is running you can put `booted` instead of `<SIMULATOR_ID>` and that will affect all runinng simulators.
running an app is done with `xcrun simctl launch <SIMULATOR_ID> <BUNDLE_ID>`

this blog post covers all of the above: https://medium.com/xcblog/simctl-control-ios-simulators-from-command-line-78b9006a20dc